# Autocompletion in Visual Studio Code: column names in R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've been using R in Visual Studio Code and at the moment it seems fantastic to me.

However, there is a function that I do not know if there is any extension or not, which is the autocompletion of column names for dataframes.
Currently, I have

[image: Image without autocompletion]

I have tried with the extension of R of VSCode and LSP server, somebody knows if it is possible that VSCode generates the following (like RStudio):

[image: Image with autocompletion in rstudio]